# Regular Expression to match statement that contain word 'abc'

Tags: regex

I handle a monitoring tools for application. I have data like this:

```
WebSphere_MB[MB7QMGR-MB7BROKER-default_abc]@esb01:2222222
WebSphere_MB[MB7QMGR-MB7BROKER-default]@esb01
WebSphere_MB[MB7QMGR-MB7BROKER-xxxabc]@esb01:11111111
WebSphere_MB[MB7QMGR-MB7BROKER-esbon2a]@esb01
WebSphere_MB[MB7QMGR-MB7BROKER-esbon2b]@esb01
WebSphere_MB[MB7QMGR-MB7BROKER-devxxx]@esb01
WebSphere_MB[MB7QMGR-MB7BROKER-defg]@esb01
```

I need to filter only statement which contains "xxxabc", "default_abc" and "devxxx" that appear in my data.

What regex should I used to do that?

Comment: You mean this https://regex101.com/r/pG8gX7/2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to select all statements which either has "abc" or "xxx".

try using `/(abc)|(xxx)/g`
or try your data with http://www.regexr.com/ - its easy to build your regEx

Below will select whole statements matching "abc" or "xxx"

```
.*?(?:abc|xxx).*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*(?:(?:xxx|default_)abc|devxxx).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/51